# Making next button continue from current "number"

Tags: javascript, jquery, cycle

I've been trying to get a next button on my site to continue from the current number. But it starts over from 1 every time. Any help i appreciated.
So what's going on here is when I click the pNext button it's supposed to change a H1 and paragraph, and cycle that between eight different options that I've created.

I have a couple of buttons that link directly to each individual array.
So a number 7 button. And if I click next after having clicked that 7 I want it to go to 8 > 1 > 2 >, and so on. But it's goes directly to 1.

```
 <!-- NEXT BUTTON -->
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var textArray = [];
            textArray[0] = "market.';    
            textArray[1] = 'area.';    
            textArray[2] = 'involved.';    
            textArray[3] = 'solution.';   
            textArray[4] = 'situation.';    
            textArray[5] = 'unit.';    
            textArray[6] = 'place.';    
            textArray[7] = 'parts.';   

            var idx = 0;
            $('#pNext').on('click', function(){
                idx++;
                var newidx = idx % textArray.length;
                $('#pText').text(textArray[newidx]);
            });
        });

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var textArray = [];
            textArray[0] = 'Better';    
            textArray[1] = 'Better';    
            textArray[2] = 'Safer';    
            textArray[3] = 'Intuitive';   
            textArray[4] = 'One';    
            textArray[5] = 'Better';    
            textArray[6] = 'Theft';    
            textArray[7] = 'Quality';   

            var idx = 0;
            $('#pNext').on('click', function(){
                idx++;
                var newidx = idx % textArray.length;
                $('#pHeadline').text(textArray[newidx]);
            });
        });

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var textArray = [];
            textArray[0] = '1';    
            textArray[1] = '2';    
            textArray[2] = '3';    
            textArray[3] = '4';   
            textArray[4] = '5';    
            textArray[5] = '6';    
            textArray[6] = '7';    
            textArray[7] = '8';   

            var idx = 0;
            $('#pNext').on('click', function(){
                idx++;
                var newidx = idx % textArray.length;
                $('#pNumber').text(textArray[newidx]);
            });
        });                   
    </script>
```

Comment: it seems to work here - https://jsfiddle.net/ezeqy5ff/4/

Comment: @freedomn-m rip me

Comment: your code looks like it contains some repetitive parts, can you at least send as the html part?

Comment: @TheWandererr If I remove that line, the code breaks..

Answer (score 1):

After access index increment variable, in your code first increment then it start from 1

```
$('#pNext').on('click', function(){
   var newidx = idx % textArray.length;
   $('#pNumber').text(textArray[newidx]);
   idx++;
});
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Answer (score 0):

Here's a new code. It works fine as per your requirement.

```
$(function() {
  var textArray = [];
  textArray[0] = 'market.';
  textArray[1] = 'area.';
  textArray[2] = 'involved.';
  textArray[3] = 'solution.';
  textArray[4] = 'situation.';
  textArray[5] = 'unit.';
  textArray[6] = 'place.';
  textArray[7] = 'parts.';

  var idx = 0;
  $('#pNext').on('click', function(){
    idx = idx == textArray.length?0:idx;
       $('#pText').text(textArray[idx++]);
    });
})
```

Comment: Hey Akhil, I'm sorry. I don't understand really. I'm quite new to java.

Comment: Don't worry, that isn't Java, it's Javascript. The first and last line should be understandable. The second line checks if the Index (idx) is smaller as the lenght (item count) of your textArray. If the Index is smaller your "#Headline"-Textcontent will be replaced with the next element from your textArray. (idx++)

Comment: But will stop at the last item.   As it's a "next" button, this is reasonable, but does not match the question code which loops back to the start.   Also, if this code was repeated 3 times for each of text/headline/number, it would jump along incorrectly.   Can you provide a complete version for all 3 sections?

Answer (score 0):

The code looks fine for me(except `textArray[0] = "market.';`). Please check the fiddle.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            var textArray = [];
            textArray[0] = 'market.';    
            textArray[1] = 'area.';    
            textArray[2] = 'involved.';    
            textArray[3] = 'solution.';   
            textArray[4] = 'situation.';    
            textArray[5] = 'unit.';    
            textArray[6] = 'place.';    
            textArray[7] = 'parts.';   

            var idx = 0;
            $('#pNext').on('click', function(){
                idx++;
                var newidx = idx % textArray.length;
                $('#pText').text(textArray[newidx]);
            });
        });

$(document).ready(function () {
            var textArray = [];
            textArray[0] = 'Better';    
            textArray[1] = 'Better';    
            textArray[2] = 'Safer';    
            textArray[3] = 'Intuitive';   
            textArray[4] = 'One';    
            textArray[5] = 'Better';    
            textArray[6] = 'Theft';    
            textArray[7] = 'Quality';   

            var idx = 0;
            $('#pNext').on('click', function(){
                debugger;
                idx++;
                var newidx = idx % textArray.length;
                $('#pHeadline').text(textArray[newidx]);
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="pText"></p>
<p id='pHeadline'></p>
<button id='pNext'>Click</button>
```